# how to get count in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I attached a page in which level field exist but when i count level it gives wrong result,here is my query:

```
select count(level) as basic from listing where a.level='70' group by a.level;
```

It gives basic=3,but only one record exist with level=70
here is page:
[image]

How i get basic=1

Comment: There is more to your query, I think.  You use the alias `a.level` but have no table in the `FROM` clause aliased as `a`.

Comment: Try attaching .JPEG files in your posts as they consume more space than .PNG!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(lst.level) as basic 
from listing lst 
where lst.level='70' 
group by lst.level;
```

You missed `from listing a` and `count(a.level)` in your query.

Comment: It would be much better if you detail where he went wrong and/or why this will work for him. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select count(level) as basic from listing where level='70';
```

Comment: but it return basic=3

Comment: try the above solution